# Creating C functions with arguments but no returns, what went wrong?

Tags: c

I have programmed a simple calculator using C with input arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void get_numbers(float, float);

void get_numbers(float a, float b)
{
  printf("Enter the first number: ");
  scanf("%f",&a);
  printf("Enter the second number: ");
  scanf("%f",&b);
}

<...>
```

Why my output floats became `0.00000` and not the input number floats?

Comment: Remember, in questions you should post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 9):

Your `void get_numbers(float a, float b)` function creates a copy of `a` and `b` on its stack. These variables are deleted upon function's exit. You should use pointers:

```
void get_numbers(float*, float*);

void get_numbers(float *a, float *b)
{
<...>
scanf("%f", a);
<...>
```

Comment: but it still conflicts with the declared function at the global area. I typed void get_numbers(float, float) there.

Comment: @SupakornSrisawat then declare it correctly: void get_numbers(float *, float *); ... void get_numbers(float *a, float *b) { ...